# Parse Json Data in Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am implementing highcharts in my mvc application. Here I am getting Json from Controller the json is like that:

```
[
    {
        "Admin_Count_ID": 1,
        "Home_Page_View": 15,
        "Month": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "Admin_Count_ID": 4,
        "Home_Page_View": 2,
        "Month": "Feb"
    }
]
```

I am using below function to show the chart and I need to parse `Month` in `xAxis.categories` and `Home_Page_View` in `series.data`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Website User View'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Users'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Users',
            data: [5, 15]

        }]
    });
});
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the required arrays with a `for` loop:

```
// assumes 'json' = the data retrieved
var months = [], views = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    months.push(json[i].Month);
    views.push(json[i].Home_Page_View)
}
```

You can then use these values in your highcharts initialisation (extra properties omitted):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: months
    },
    series: [{
        data: views
    }]
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wktf38mo/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{"Admin_Count_ID":1,"Home_Page_View":15,"Month":"Jan"},{"Admin_Count_ID":4,"Home_Page_View":2,"Month":"Feb"}];

var month = [];
var view = [];
$.each(obj,function(index,val){
    month.push(val.Month);
    view.push(val.Home_Page_View);
});
```

In Your highCharts write like

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: month
        },
series: [{
        name: 'Users',
        data: view
    }]
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkwx4rqr/1/)**